# Vue - execute method on blur when no input focused

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, event-handling

I'm trying to find a way to prevent method execution when any of 2 inputs have focus.

Both inputs should fire method on blur and prevent it when focused. Using single of these inputs works good.

The problematic situation is when blurring from *input_1* and immediately focusing on *input_2* (e.g. using tab) - it fires the method before *input_2* gets focus.

What I would like to achieve is preventing the method execution in this case.

What I already tried:

- using flags as presented in example code -> failed as described,
- getting activeElement in fired method -> instead of getting input element, I'm getting main vue app `<div id="app" />`

Example code:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <input id="input_1" @blur="changeFlagAndExecuteMethod()" @focus="focused = true"></input>
    <input id="input_2" @blur="changeFlagAndExecuteMethod()" @focus="focused = true"></input>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      focused: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    changeFlagAndExecuteMethod () {
      this.focused = false
      this.doSomething()
    },
    doSomething () {
      // document.activeElement => results with main <div id="app" /> instead of input

      if (this.focused) return
      // otherwise execute method
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Could you not just disable the inputs when the `changeFlagAndExecuteMethod` function is operating?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy but I want to keep them enable. What I want is catching in doSomething method that I focused in any input.

Comment: I edited the code - in doSomething I want to check if focused = true and if it is return from executing doSomething method

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to execute `doSomething()` in the next macro tick, using `setTimeout()` with a zero delay (`ms` is 0 by default), at which point the second input will have received focus, and its `focus` handler will already have been invoked:

```js
changeFlagAndExecuteMethod () {
  this.focused = false
  setTimeout(() => this.doSomething()) // execute in next macro tick
}
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/eYJRBgQ)